# Conflicto con select javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, smarty

les pasó a explicar lo que me esta pasando.

Tengo este HTML, en el cual usó Smarty

```
<select id="filtro" class="form-select" style="width:150px;">
    <option value="e"{# if $tsSelect == 'e' #} selected{# /if #}>Estado</option>
    <option value="f"{# if $tsSelect == 'f' #} selected{# /if #}>Fecha</option>
    <option value="ip"{# if $tsSelect == 'ip' #} selected{# /if #}>IP</option>
</select>
```

y luego he agregado este código

```
<script>
filtro = document.getElementById("filtro")
filtro.addEventListener('change', () => {
    let normal = "d",
    value = filtro.options[filtro.selectedIndex].value,
    search = window.location.search;
    if(search != '') {
        if (typeof URLSearchParams !== 'undefined') {
            p = new URLSearchParams(search);
            p.delete('o');
            search = p.toString().split('=')[1];
        }
        normal = (search == 'd') ? "a" : "d";
    }
    // http://localhost/admin/posts?o=e&m=d
    location.href = "{# $tsConfig.url #}/admin/posts?o=" + value + "&m=" + normal; 
})  
</script>
```

Bien hasta funciona todo correcto, selecciono una opción recarga y agrega en la url lo que corresponde, pero el problema se encuentra en la opción que tenga "**selected**" ya que si le doy clic para volver a seleccionar para cambiar de **d** => **a**, no hace nada, ni siquiera recarga.

Si en la url es así **localhost/admin/posts?o=f&m=d** se agrega el selected en **Fecha** pero cuando vuelvo a dar clic debería pasar a **localhost/admin/posts?o=f&m=a**...

He buscado información, he probado algunas formas pero no he conseguido solucionarlo!

Espero haberme explicado correctamente.

Comment: Por alguna razón, me borra la primera parte... Ya que estoy saludando, lo que falta es "Hola a todos...."

Comment: No hay conflicto, lo que pasa es que el evento `change` no se va a disparar si _"seleccionas"_ un valor que ya está seleccionado. Tal vez podría hacerse con _radios_ y el evento `click`  en cada uno.